# building with cordova for android creates wrong version code

Tags: android, cordova

running the command `cordova build --release android` produces an apk that has a version code of 70. in the config.xml file, for the widget i have set it as

```
<widget id="com.example.myapp"
        android-versionCode="7"
        version="0.9.1"
        >
```

How do I get cordova-cli to build an apk with version code 7?

Running `aapt.exe l -a` on the generated apk shows `A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x46` 0x46 being 70, if I jarsigner the apk, and zipalign and upload, google also tells me the version code is 70.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem in that under `platforms/android/build.gradle`, on line 178,

```
versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode") + "0")
```

at the end is that `+ "0"` thus turning my version code from 7 to 70. Removing the `+ "0"` at the end and changing line 178 to the following solved this problem.

```
versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
```

Running `aapt.exe l -a` on the generated apk now shows `A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x7`

Comment: sed -i"" -e "s/ + \"0\"//" platforms/android/build.gradle

Comment: Why oh why do they add the 0 at the end? It makes no sense at all!

Comment: After some update, this is now on line 175 for me.  Also Chi-An's answer may be relevant if you are getting an extra 2 or 4 in there, and if you are getting an extra 9 or 8 added to it, (i.e. creating version 10 results in 18, or with out the fix above version 10 creates version 108) those are found on lines ~210 and ~212, simply commenting out these lines works fine i.e.`//defaultConfig.versionCode += 8`.

Comment: sed -i"" -e '/^[^\/]*defaultConfig\.versionCode\s+\+=/ s/.*/\/\/&/'

Comment: I would be cautious about this. They are appending a `0` because in the next 20-30 lines of the gradle file, they are adding 2, 4, 8, or 9 to the versionCode. So if you are build `507`, and it is coming out `5078`, and you take out the `+ "0"`, you will end up seeing build `515`. It seems they are trying to co-opt the versionCode to store some information about release platform. I don't quite understand why they feel they need to do this....

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I'm using Cordova 4.3.0. My versionCode in the AndroidManifest.xml was "1" and the versionCode in the .apk was coming through as "12". If you look at the chunk of code after the line you reference, building multiple versions will append a "2" for arm7 and a "4" for x86. I sort of see why this was done, but it seems to me it's better to let developers determine the versionCode they want.