# Ionic Android versioning fails

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem with the version numbers in the Play store.

Versions of my app used to be formated like

```
Version code
10172   (5 digits)
Version name
1.1.72
```

I changed the build machine and didn't realize that the version I uploaded had

```
Version code
101748
```

Now 6t digits! the 8 extends the version number to be too long

```
Version name
1.1.74
```

`101748` now is blocking me from uploading a new version to the store. 
For instance, for version `1.1.821` in the `config.xml` I get an APK of version code `101748` again!?!?! and upload fails with

```
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 101748.
```

I had other build combinations where the version code was 5 digits again and upload failed.

I can not remove the currently uploaded version from the play store and I do not know how to adjust the automated build system in ionic to force it to use a specific version code? It seems the code is generated out of the version during build.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: you with can fix following two : change android:versionCode="your version(10182)" or make change version = "1.8.2" and make release .apk again for upload..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, took me a while, but to fix this one has to split

```
cordova build --release android
```

into

```
cordova prepare android
./adjustVersionCode.py 
cordova compile android --release
```

with `adjustVersionCode.py` in un-optimized and cleaned python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lxml import etree

lines = ''
with open('config.xml','r') as configFile:
    for line in configFile.readlines():
        lines += line

configXML = etree.fromstring(lines)

versionNumber = configXML.attrib['version']
versionCode = versionNumber.replace('.','')

if len(versionCode) < 6:
    versionCode += '0'

print versionNumber,versionCode


lines = ''
with open('./platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml','r') as configFile:
    for line in configFile.readlines():
        lines += line

androidManifestXML = etree.fromstring(lines)

wrongVersion = androidManifestXML.attrib['{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}versionCode']

replaceString = 'android:versionCode="'+str(wrongVersion)+'"'
replaceWith = 'android:versionCode="'+str(versionCode)+'"'

lines = ''
with open('./platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml','r') as configFile:
    for line in configFile.readlines():
        lines += line.replace(replaceString,replaceWith)


with open('./platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml','w') as configFile:
    for line in lines:
        configFile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, **edit your config.xml**, add "android-versionCode" and specify your versionCode manually:

```
widget id="com.xxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyy" android-versionCode="201018"
version="2.1.1"
```

Comment: Totally worked! Thanks! (using ionic v2.2.2 and cordova v6.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

See ["building with cordova for android creates wrong version code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854346/building-with-cordova-for-android-creates-wrong-version-code)

But since your current version on the store is `101748` you'll need to have that be at least `101749` in order to upload a new version. There's no way to undo this on google, so you'll need to just start from this number, or upload as an entirely new app.